Como puedo utilizar BsDatepickerModule en Angular 17
No se como importar el BsDatepickerModule en Angular 17 para poder usarlo. el bsConfig no me lo reconoce.
<input (input)="ponerPrecio();actualizarFechaSalida()"
                   [min]="fechaHoy"
                   [(ngModel)]="fechaEntrada"
                   #fechaInicioInput
                   name="fechaInicio"
                   type="date"
                   class="bg-gray-50 border border-gray-300 text-gray-900 text-sm rounded-lg focus:ring-blue-500 focus:border-blue-500 block w-full ps-10 p-2.5"
                   placeholder="Fecha de entrada"
                   [bsConfig]="{ dateInputFormat: 'YYYY-MM-DD', isDisabled: fechaEstaBloqueada }">


Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

¿Lo has añadido a las dependencias de tu módulo principal?

Si y aun asi no lo reconoce

Comparte más código para ver cual es el problema, si es Angular 17 probablemente sea un Standalone Component por lo que me parece tienes que importar las dependencias en el componente.
